# How to use the results of a select in another select in a union query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, subquery

I have a union query, where I want to use the results of the select in the "left side" of the union query, in the select statement on the "right side" of the union query. The query below works correctly (on postgres at least), but I am running query1 2 times, once as query1, and again as sameAsQuery1.

```
select x as zz from (select 69 as x) as query1
union all
select count(zz) as zz from 
      (select x as zz from (select 69 as x) as sameAsQuery1) as query2
```

I would like to do something like this so I don't have to run query1 2 times, but it doesn't work:

```
select x as zz from (select 69 as x) as query1
union all
select count(zz) as zz from query1
```

I get this error message:

> ERROR:  relation "query1" does not exist LINE 3:     select count(zz)
>   as zz from query1

Is there a way to rewrite this query so query1 only runs once?

Minor modification to Mr. Llama's response worked quite well, it looks like this (Note the addition of "as q2"):

```
WITH
query1 AS
(
    SELECT x AS zz FROM (SELECT 69 AS x) as q2
)
SELECT zz FROM query1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(zz) AS zz FROM query1
```

Comment: please show some sample data and the expected result

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using?

Comment: The data is contained in the queries themselves.

Comment: @Mr. Llama's response, with a minor modification, worked well.

Comment: `select x as zz from (select 69 as x) as query1` can be replaced with a simple `select 69` or just `values (69)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [common table expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html).

They let you define a result and use it multiple times within a query.

In your fist case:

```
WITH
query1 AS
(
    SELECT x AS zz FROM (SELECT 69 AS x)
)
SELECT zz FROM query1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(zz) AS zz FROM query1
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would do something like this when most databases support `group by` and `rollup`?  It seems you want something like this:

```
select x, count(*) as cnt
from <whatever>
group by x with rollup;
```

Comment: Postgres does not (yet) support rollup (I think it will be in the upcoming 9.5 though)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . In my defense, it was not tagged Postgres when I answered the question.  (And Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, Teradata, and DB2 -- and probably others too -- do support it or something similar.)

Answer (score 0):

Put the query1 result into temp table

```
select x as zz from (select 69 as x) as query1 into temptable
```

Now use the temp table in second query

```
select zz from temptable
union all
select count(zz) as zz from temptable
```

Comment: Using the non-standard `select .. into ..` is discouraged. It's better to use the standard `create table .. as select ..` syntax (plus a temp table isn't necessary in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a Common Table Expression to reuse the SELECT:

```
with cte as
( select x as zz from (select 69 as x) as query1 )
select * from cte
union all
select count(zz) as zz from cte
```